# Can I upgrade my Macbook pro 13 inch mid 2009's logic board?

Tags: macbook-pro, upgrade, gpu, cpu, logicboard

I want to upgrade my Macbook Pro 13 inch mid 2009's logic board with a new quad core i7 and 2gb or more radeon graphics. I have a few questions:

1. Will this affect my OSX installation?
2. Are Macbook Pro 15 inch and 17 inch boards compatible with 13 inch?
3. Will the power supply suffice?

Please send models of logic boards that are compatible.

Thanks

Comment: Essentially, no laptop is upgradeable in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'problem' with Mac laptops is that generally they are not upgradable except for RAM and HD/SSD and sometimes the battery. And newer Mac laptops none of the above.

At one time I had heard of Mac laptops with video cards that were on a daughter card of sorts. So theoretically replaceable but no one ever made a replacement to my knowledge.

This is becoming more and more common to find laptops from other manufacturers where there is little, if anything to upgrade. It is (probably?) a side-effect of the push for smaller/lighter making modular parts less and less of a reasonable (from an engineering/design standpoint) option.

So essentially what Tetsujin is correct: you have no upgrade path for system boards, CPUs and the like.

Comment: It's a shame how soldered together they are now a days.  I would prefer user replacement and slightly larger then the smallness factor they are going for now a days.

Comment: @William In general, though, laptops don't have upgradable logic boards. The boards are designed for the laptop model.

Comment: Will it not work even with another macs logic board? What about this- https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/MacBook+Pro+13-Inch+Unibody+Mid+2009+Logic+Board+Replacement/1363?

Comment: @MythicCocoa you can replace a mid-2009 logic board with another one from mid-2009, but not with one from a different model. Also, logic boards are sized to the computer, so a 17" model won't work in a 13" computer and vice versa.

Comment: @noahl I've heard about people upgrading to Macbook pro 2010 logic boards, but that doesn't make the "2017 cut" either. If it is possible to swap a 2010 mobo in, then it should be the same for newer models with i5s and i7s, right? After searching the web for logic board replacements possibilities, I found that the position of a few slots has changed in newer models, but it's still possible. I've already installed more ram and an ssd in my mac, but that can only improve performance by so much. If upgrading the logic board is truly impossible, I'll be forced to sell my Mac for a measly $250 ;(

Answer (score 0):

I replaced my MacBook Pro 2009 13” Logicboard with a MacBook Pro 2010 Logicboard with success. The two boards have the same mounts and connections.